# How to know which custom domain a request was made to with Cloud Run?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, custom-domain

I am prototyping a smart link service in Go using Google Cloud Run. I need to know **which domain/hostname has been used to call my Cloud Run service** (e.g., the default .run.app, or one of many custom mapped domains).

I created a check endpoint (`/__hitcheck`) that returns the current HTTP request's referer, headers, and URL, as JSON.

I've checked fields I'd expect to show the current domain called, in vain:

- `r.URL.String() = "/__hitcheck"` (my test endpoint)
- `r.URL.Host = ""`

And nothing's in the request headers either.

**So, how can I know if somebody called `/__hitcheck` from the Cloud Run service URL directly or one of many custom domains?**

The redacted JSON payload:

```
{
    "r.Header": {
        "Accept": [
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
        ],
        "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        "Accept-Language": [
            "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        ],
        "Cookie": [
            "...some stuff..."
        ],
        "Early-Data": [
            "1"
        ],
        "Forwarded": [
            "for=\"MY IP\";proto=https"
        ],
        "Referer": [
            "https://example.com/some-blog-post/"
        ],
        "Sec-Ch-Ua": [
            "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"107\", \"Chromium\";v=\"107\", \"Not=A?Brand\";v=\"24\""
        ],
        "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": [
            "?0"
        ],
        "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": [
            "\"macOS\""
        ],
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": [
            "document"
        ],
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": [
            "navigate"
        ],
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": [
            "cross-site"
        ],
        "Sec-Fetch-User": [
            "?1"
        ],
        "Traceparent": [
            "some request ID"
        ],
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": [
            "1"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        ],
        "X-Cloud-Trace-Context": [
            "some request ID"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
            "MY IP"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ]
    },
    "r.Referer()": "https://example.com/some-blog-post/",
    "r.RequestURI": "/__hitcheck",
    "r.URL": {
        "Scheme": "",
        "Opaque": "",
        "User": null,
        "Host": "",
        "Path": "/__hitcheck",
        "RawPath": "",
        "OmitHost": false,
        "ForceQuery": false,
        "RawQuery": "",
        "Fragment": "",
        "RawFragment": ""
    },
    "r.URL.String()": "/__hitcheck"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP `Host` header specifies the host and port number of the server to which the request is being sent.

I verified that with a Swift Cloud Run instance. Click both links and scroll down to the `host` header.

[Cloud Run URL](https://swift-request-e2v2ixiywa-uc.a.run.app/)

[Cloud Run Custom Domain](https://swift-request.jhanley.com/)

The Swift code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/jhanley-com/swift/tree/master/Google-Cloud/Cloud-Run/SwiftRequest). Similar techniques will work for a Cloud Run Go application.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, it seems like the host is specified in `http.Request.Host`, rather than the headers or `http.Request.URL.Host`.